# trigger “an instructor cannot teach in two different classrooms in a semester in the same time slot.”

Tags: sql, triggers, referential-integrity

Show how to enforce the constraint “an instructor cannot teach in two
different classrooms in a semester in the same time slot.” using a trigger
(remember that the constraint can be violated by changes to the teaches
relation as well as to the section relation).

I am self-learning SQL using Database System Concept and get pretty confused about[see the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WHMt.png) how trigger is enforced. Any inputs are appreciated!

Comment: The trigger can raise an error and effectively abort the transaction. The syntax is different for each DB. What DB are you learning?

Comment: Thanks, cha. The textbook I am reading does not deal with a certain DB. It only broadly talks about SQL in general.  Below is an example from the textbook. I am not sure if the code is executable or not.                                     create trigger timeslot check1 after insert on section
referencing new row as nrow
for each row
when (nrow.time slot id not in (
select time slot id
from time slot)) /* time slot id not present in time slot */
begin
rollback
end;

Comment: I guess in this case you can just `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`

Comment: Thanks! I just upload the book code http://i.stack.imgur.com/9WHMt.png. Do you think I should write the same way?

Comment: Yes, rollback is a pretty standard way to control the data integrity

Comment: Thank you! Could you write a short code to implement this question? I am kind of confused to make out the meaning of the sentence